# libCURL or Boost for network programming?

Tags: boost, network-programming, libcurl

I'm starting to learn network programming in C++ and since the standard library doesn't support networking, I have to resort to one of these. Which do you think is simpler and thus, easier to learn?

Comment: You do not need to use boost or libcurl; the "standard library" most certainly does support networking. After all, if it didn't, how would libcurl or boost do their jobs?

Comment: The C++ standard library does not support networking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They do different things.

If you're looking for HTTP, FTP, and support for a slew of other protocols, then use libcurl.  If you want to directly use sockets and implement all your own protocols, then use Boost Asio.

A third choice would be to use the [Pion Network Library](http://www.pion.org/projects/pion-network-library), which is built on top of Asio.  It only supports HTTP, though, and for clients is more of a building block than a ready-made solution.